# Does ActiveWorkbook.Name return a string? New issue: says "file corrupted"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing an Excel module using VBA to rename a filename by concatenating a cell value and the current filename.

My full code looks like this:

```
Sub cellvalue_filename ()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim WBname

    Path = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test\"
    WBname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    filename = Path & Range("B2") & WBname & ".csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

I am getting a runtime error 1004 using the line: `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, xlCSV` but I think that the original problem might be from using `WBname = ActiveWorkbook.Name` as I originally removed labeling it `As String` because it gave me an error for wrong type. I'm not sure if this is the issue or if FileFormat is wrong. I'm using Windows and the file extension says .csv, so not sure if that is the actual issue.

I have corrected the issue before by printing the filename before trying to save, but now it's giving me the error that it is the file I'm trying to rename is corrupted or in a different location. Is this because I'm trying to rename the file? Is this not possible? Here's the updated code.

```
Sub cellvalue_filename()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim WBname

    Path = "C:\Users\user\filename"
    WBname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    filename = Path & Range("B2") & WBname
    MsgBox (filename)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename, xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint (F9) on the `filename =` line, inspect the value of the local variables. Press F8 once, inspect the value of `filename`. Looks valid?

Comment: You might need to do `filename = Path & Range("B2") & "\" & WBname & ".csv"`

Comment: I just wonder out of curiosity, do you have any special characters or strange name in the cell B2?

Comment: In B2 there are forward-slashes

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveWorkbook` is a `Workbook` object. So let's look at the properties of the `Workbook` class. Press F2 to bring up the *object browser*, locate the `Workbook` class, scroll to the `Name` property:

[image: Workbook class members]

Yup, definitely a string.

You are making an assumption about the *content* of the string, not the *type*. Verify that you're passing a valid file name to the `Workbook.SaveAs` method.